# finding numbers that can be divided to 3

Tags: arrays, sorting, integer

I'm trying to find numbers that can be divided into 3, I try to find results that are integers after a number is divided to 3.

What do you think is the problem here?

```
enter function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i = 0;
  var d = i / 3;
  while (i < 1001) 
    if number.isInteger(d) {
    text += "<br>" + d;
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementById("divv").innerHTML = text;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you using specific programming language or pseudo-code? If it's JavaScript you should have parentheses around condition '(Number.isInteger(d))'. Your code snippet is not a minimal reproducible example. Check out how to make one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the modulo function (%) in JavaScript.

In your code, you have the incrementer i++ within your if statement, so this code will actually never stop running. You made an infinite loop.

Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click "Try it" </p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="divv"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var text = "";
  var i = 0;

  while (i < 1001) {
    if ((i % 3 === 0) && i> 0) {
    text += "<br> " + i  + " is divisible by 3";    
     }
      i++;
      document.getElementById("divv").innerHTML = text;
  }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It looks like you are beginner and a great site to learn from is: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_examples.asp

Comment: Thank you, actually the example is from w3schools, which I messed a bit.